# Efficient way to do recursion with objects in Java?

Tags: java, recursion

In dynamic programming using Java I frequently want to pass an array or object as a parameter in the recursive step. However, in order to have the original value be un-modified I would have to clone the object before passing it in as a parameter; by doing so I would have a very unfavorable time and space complexity since the method could have thousands of stacks. I read from [Is there a more efficient way passing object parameters in recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45715068/is-there-a-more-efficient-way-passing-object-parameters-in-recursion) that a possible method to overcome this problem could be by undoing the process after completing the computation. However, sometimes this is impossible to undo(for instance when the recursive method remove element(s) from the array). Does anyone have a solution to this problem? I am using this in the context of competitive programming and sometimes a bottom-up solution would be far too complex and impractical.

An example:

```java
public static int method(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    if(list.size()==1) {
        return list.get(0);
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> clone = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int e:list) {
        clone.add(e);
    }
    clone.remove(clone.size()-1);
    method(clone);            
}
```

If I did not clone it and did this instead:

```java
public static int method(ArrayList<Integer> list){
    if(list.size()==1) {
        return list.get(0);
    }
    list.remove(list.size()-1);
    method(list);            
}
```

the original object would be modified. In this case, one can obviously just return the first element of the array instead of creating this cuber-stone code. However, my point is to illustrate the problem of passing object.

Comment: Use immutable data structures. There are multiple libraries available.

Comment: To expand on @thatotherguy's comment, either the objects need to be mutated or they don't. If not, make them immutable.  Passing object references is already as "efficient" as it gets and there's no reason to clone objects given the other mechanisms at your disposal to prevent inadvertent modification.

Comment: Can you be specific, what type of recursive problem are you running into where you actually need a true copy?

Comment: @JimGarrison The reason I need to clone objects is because when we pass an object into a method, the object is not copied rather it's memory location is copied. Hence, if the method modifies the object, the original object will also be modified.

Comment: @thatotherguy In competitive programming one does not bring a library into the contest and it would be a waste of time creating a immutable array/object.

Comment: It is hard to give optimal solution to your problem without knowing exact use case. But another potential approach can be a thin wrapper object that will delegate read methods to original object and internally keep track of changes. This way expensive state can still be contained in the original object.

Comment: Immutability is as simple as making all data members private and not providing setters or mutating methods.  Essentially no “cost” at all.  Your example is too contrived to demonstrate your real use case.

Comment: As a side note: for efficiency try `Collections.addAll(clone, list);`

Answer (score 1):

To the extent an answer exists to so generic a question (and understanding the rationale for the generality), it is [persistent data structures](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure).  These are what is used to do efficient computation in languages like Haskell where everything is immutable and all algorithms are based on recursion, so they are certainly appropriate for your case.  That said, Java is not optimized for such operations, so you may find that solutions that *sound* clumsier are faster to code and/or execute in practice.

Answer (score 1):

If you need your List or Array of something as it has been before, then you can just copy it once before modifying the copied version recursively, but you don't need to copy it at every recursive step.